# Is there a way to have Visual Studio's Watch list evaluate using Preprocessor Definitions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

In my project, I have a large number of array indices which are defined with the preprocessor.  This presents a problem when debugging, because the watch window does not seem to be able to evaluate these expressions.  In these scenarios, I have found it necessary to manually look up the the defined index and substitute the value into the watch expression.

Using an enumeration for the indices would solve more problems than this, but this would be a politically difficult move at this point, which leads to my desire for a workaround.

Comment: I'm thinking there is no work-around besides the one you mentioned.  Have you tried the immediate window, or does it give you the same behavior?

Comment: Post to programmers.se to find way to educate the politicians about the way the preprocessor works.